# Can't get my timer to start when I click on my buttons

Tags: javascript, timer

I am trying to get my buttons to start counting down when I select a specific time.
As of now when I click on one it only shows the time, it doesn't start the countdown.

```
 <html>
     <div class="app">
        <div class="time-select">
        <button data-time="120">2 Minutes</button>
        <button data-time="300">5 Minutes</button>
        <button data-time="600">10 Minutes</button>
    </div>

    <div class="timer-container">
            <h3 class="time-display">0:00</h3>
        </div>
  </div>
 </html>


     const timeDisplay = document.querySelector(".time-display");

     const timeSelect = document.querySelectorAll(".time-select button");


     let fakeDuration = 600;
 
      timeSelect.forEach(option => {    
      option.addEventListener("click", function(){    
      fakeDuration = this.getAttribute("data-time");    
      timeDisplay.textContent = `${Math.floor(fakeDuration / 60)}:${Math.floor(fakeDuration % 
      60)}`;
      });
    });


      ontimeUpdate = () => {
        let elapsed = fakeDuration;
        let seconds = Math.floor(elapsed % 60);
        let minutes = Math.floor(elapsed / 60);

    timeDisplay.textContent = `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
};
```

Comment: I don't see that you have used a setInterval method.  Without that your code will run once and be done. A good example can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) - additionally I fixed the way you calculate minutes and seconds. JS uses milliseconds - it's generally best to standardize time-keeping/counting to fit into JS's existing rules.

```js
const timeDisplay = document.querySelector(".time-display");
const timeSelect = document.querySelectorAll(".time-select button");
let fakeDuration, interval

timeSelect.forEach(option => {
  option.addEventListener("click", function() {
    clearInterval(interval)
    fakeDuration = +this.getAttribute("data-time");
      interval = setInterval( () =>  ontimeUpdate(), 1000)
  });
});


ontimeUpdate = () => {
  fakeDuration -= 1000;
  if (fakeDuration <= 0) clearInterval(interval)
  let minutes = ('0' + Math.floor(fakeDuration / 60000)).slice(-2);
  let seconds = ('0' + (fakeDuration % 60000)/1000).slice(-2);
  timeDisplay.textContent = `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
};
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="time-select">
    <button data-time="120000">2 Minutes</button>
    <button data-time="300000">5 Minutes</button>
    <button data-time="600000">10 Minutes</button>
  </div>

  <div class="timer-container">
    <h3 class="time-display">0:00</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should probably clear the interval when the timer hits zero

Comment: Great point, thanks @Steve

Comment: This is a bit off topic, however, if interested instead of getting the attribute `data-time` you can just read it via the dataset property `+this.dataset.time`. More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes#javascript_access

Comment: I got you. Thanks for the help. I'm new to JavaScript and I'm trying to understand how it works. I've been stuck on this for a two days researching and trying to figure it out and I finally caved in and ask for help. Ha

Comment: @seanrandevs - if you're confused as to what is happening here, be sure to ask.